# How to get the full filename of the files starting with matching characters in a directory?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to get the full filename of the files in a directory that starts with for example `SVR_OUTPUT_` just to validate if the file exists in the directory using batch script.

I was successful to get the file name in the directory to compare the names using:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
:: Load the file path "array"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('dir /s /b^|findstr /n "^"') do (
  set "file.%%A=%%B"
  set "file.count=%%A"
)

:: Access the values
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%N in (1 1 %file.count%) do echo !file.%%N!
```

But I need to compare and check if the file names starts with `SVR_OUTPUT_`. I'm new to batch programming.

Could any one help me with this?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use an array instead of processing the file names directly in one simple `for` loop?

Comment: No, the thought was to get the file name into an array and iterate thru it to  compare and match...

Comment: Use wildcards: `dir /s /b SVR_OUTPUT_*` will list all files that start with `SVR_OUTPUT_` and much faster than manual iteration.

Comment: Thank you so much wOxxOm! just a single line gave me the result.. Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written already by [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom), all you need for listing all files from all subdirectories starting with `SVR_OUTPUT_` is:

```
dir /S /B SVR_OUTPUT_*
```

Remove `/S` to get listed just the files in current directory not including subdirectories or a message that no file matching the pattern could be found.

The following code could be used to check if in current directory there is at least 1 file starting with `SVR_OUTPUT_`:

```
@echo off
if exist SVR_OUTPUT_* (
    echo There are follwing files starting with SVR_OUTPUT_ in %CD%
    echo.
    dir /B /ON SVR_OUTPUT_*
) else (
    echo There is no file starting with SVR_OUTPUT_ in %CD%
)
pause
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!